# How to tackle overfitting with fully convolutional network in caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have a fully convolutional network (specifically the stacked hourglass network) in caffe. After each convolutional layer I have a batch normalisation and a scale layer and a ReLU layer. However, I encounter the problem of overfitting. Usually, I would increase my dataset (which is not possible) or I would use Dropout layers, but since I have read that it is not useful to use Dropout layers in fully convolutional networks I have no idea how to tackle the problem. Are there any things to do apart from what I have mentioned. Might Regulariztion be helpful in this case?

Comment: try to increase your dataset with augmentation functions (crop, flip, invert, scale, translate, rotate, etc...)

Comment: Data augmentation is great when it is reasonned. Don't go full out on it without thinking : your goal is to train your network on variations which are not present in the original training set **but that you know can happen in the testing set**. For example, if you're working on images of surveillance of streets, there is no point in flipping it 180 degrees as no image shown to your neural network will ever look like that either in train or in validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a handy picture I stole from the interwebs.  It is a handy chart of things to try when your deep learning model is having trouble.  You say that you have heard that Dropout isn't good in Conv, but have you tested it?  Start with that and proceed thusly :

1. Add dropout to Conv layer with a large depth dimension that is close to the output
2. Try **not going deep**.  This is the reverse of *go deep*, which you should try before *going deep*.  Make sure you have a simple model that doesn't overfit **first**, then try adding layers.
3. If you are still overfitting and you have dropout then try removing **neurons** by making your later Conv layers not have as much depth.
4. Do what Z.Kal says, multiply your dataset by transforming it.
5. And if all that doesn't make a difference accept the fact that your architecture is probably wrong.  You have buried deep in it a way for it to store all the data you feed it verbatim without generalizing it.  Consider making a squeeze point, where you have a layer that is small compared to the input data.

[image]

**update 2020/10/22** - After several years of coding convolution and experimenting with reasons why my embedding layers seems to have unreasonably high covariance issues I have tracked it down to dropout.  *Dropout encourages covariance* (which is not good btw).  Instead of dropout, I use other regularizers or just skip regularization altogether and focus on initialization and architecture.  Here is a (bad) video I made showing how to effectively train a super deep [400 layers of convolution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS-ULgwkheE) and the tricks used to help get it trained and operational

Comment: Hm my network is very deep and I am using the stacked-hourglass-network. I have a simple dataset which consists of 10.000 data samples which works quite fine with a little bit of overfitting. Then I have a dataset of 800.000 data samples which does not converge at all. I have tried to simplify the dataset of 800.000 samples to 5.000 samples then it converges as well but it overfits. What do you think about that?

Comment: That is interesting and would prompt me to question the 800,000 set and do some exploration!  I work with text analysis a lot and I've found huge subsets of the labeled data that I have to be grossly mislabeled, so I've had to explore the data to identify these areas and just exclude them.  Fortunately I have metadata about the text (like data and team that labeled it) that you may not have about the images.  So, without that kind of information I'd divide the 800,000 into 80 batches of 10,000 and see what happens.  I'd also try starting with the 10,000 model and retrain it on the minibatchs

Comment: As for overfitting, you probably have a fully connected layer at the end of your network.  try increasing it by 50% and adding a 50% dropout to it.  A dropout of 20% (.8) in the Conv layers i've seen often.  I'd be interested in your minibatch size, share please.  Personally I've found in most cases a minibatch size as small as 5 overcomes most problems of SGD and a batch size of over 100 has high computation cost without benefit, so I tend to start with 20.  If you are using a really large batch size then it will just take way too long to see results.

Comment: First I do not have a fully connected layer that´s what I said my network is fully-convolutional. Secondly, what does `mini_batch` size regarding caffe exactly mean? Is it the `batch_size` param in Caffe? I have set my `batch_size` to 4 since this is the highest number I can have without getting data out of memory. But then I train on 4 GPUs which makes the batch size 4*4 = 16. Is that correct?

Comment: good feedback, it helps.  If it is fully convolutional then stick with a small dropout like 20%.  Yes, **batch_size** is what I'm referring to.  Finally, I'm not sure how caffe sets up the multi-gpu w.r.t batch_size.  Sorry.